# How to split a string in java with a specified delimiter while ignoring /?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

I tried to read about regex and escaping, but no luck.

I have a string that looks like this:

```
String s = "4/18/2015|Planned|Linux|Maintenance";
```

And I want to split it with the delimiter '|' :

```
String[] tokens = s.split("|");
```

The correct results I am expecting which are

```
tokens[0] is "4/18/2015", 
tokens[1] is "Planned", 
tokens[2] is "Linux", 
token[3] is "Maintenance",
```

yet it's giving me some weird result like this:

```
tokens[0] is null
tokens[1] is 4
tokens[2] is /
and tokens[3] is 1
```

I am guessing it's because of the slashes '/' in the date that's why. I tried to search for many existing questions and tried the suggested methods as well but to no avail.

Comment: What is 'some weird result'?

Comment: `Please help me and I will upvote the right answers and accept the best. `  that is pretty obvious and expected too :)

Comment: check this out, https://ideone.com/qZcIFF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
split("\\x7C")
```

or

```
split("\\|")
```

You need to escape or use corresponding unicode value when splitting against the pipeline char '|'.

Comment: I tried your previous suggestion split("\\|") and it worked. I need to accept your answer but it's not letting me to do so it has a 10 minutes limit. I will accept your answer later.

Comment: What you call the "hex code" here is the unicode code point; note that this is only available since Java 7!

Comment: Thanks for the info man. Made the edit.

Answer (score 4):

[@mushfek0001 got it right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29405183/1093528).

The pipe in most regex dialects is a metacharacter for the alternation; basically what you ask the regex engine to do here is: "split against the empty string or... the empty string".

And, uh, it means you would potentially get empty each time, except that the regex engine is not a fool, and if an empty match is detected in a split the engine will advance one character before splitting again... Hence your result (not sure why the first element is `null` and not the empty string, though).

Therefore, you should split against `"\\|"`, not `"|"`.

What is more, if you do this repeatedly, use a `Pattern` instead:

```
private static final Pattern PIPE = Pattern.compile("\\|");

// ...

final String[] tokens = PIPE.split(yourInput);
```

Comment: That's some nice info der!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks fge! It helps a lot! I should have accepted yours yet mushfek0001 came to solve my problem earlier. Thank you so much fge I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

escape the pipe character:

```
s.split("\\|");
```

because pipe sign in regex means OR, so to escape it you need `\|` but in regex you need to escape `\` too so `\\|` will work.

or as mushfek0001 suggested:

```
split("\\x7C")
```